# AEM 6.5 Venia - Corevenia.core in console throwing error

Tags: java, maven, adobe, aem, venia

I am very new to AEM 6.5, So basically I set up AEM in Ubuntu 20. I set up the requirement for AEM and its working fine, Next, when I thought of customizing the theme venia which I cloned from the GitHub link `https://github.com/adobe/aem-cif-guides-venia`, as I have started as per GitHub steps first I ran

`mvn clean install -PautoInstallSinglePackage,cloud`

after that, the BUILD was a success, but when referring to the console the following error is showing as attached, and list

```
com.adobe.cq.commerce.core.components.models.common,version=[1.8,2) -- Cannot be resolved
com.adobe.cq.commerce.core.components.models.productteaser,version=[2.0,3) -- Cannot be resolved
com.adobe.cq.commerce.core.components.models.retriever,version=[1.11,2) -- Cannot be resolved
```

[image]

I could not find any solution for the error. Any Help will be appreciated !!

Comment: What version of AEM 6.4 are you using? Venia and the CIF Core Components work on 6.4.4.0 and above. (AEM 6.4 SP 4).

Comment: Sry Daniel Its AEM 6.5 I have confirmed now

Comment: Can you explain how the `oci-java-sdk` is related to your question or problem? `oci-java-sdk` is the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure SDK for Java: https://github.com/oracle/oci-java-sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not install Venia on AEM 6.4 using the `cloud` profile. You should install it using the `classic` profile:
`mvn clean install -PautoInstallSinglePackage,classic`

From the [README](https://github.com/adobe/aem-cif-guides-venia/blob/main/README.md):

```
* classic: this profile is for Abobe Managed Services (AMS) or on-premise deployments.
```

Also, I'm not sure that the latest Venia sample app is supported on AEM 6.4.4.0

Comment: That solved two errors of my thanks, Daniel, again having error in `cq.commerce.core.components.models`

Comment: Again, I'm not sure that the latest Venia supports AEM 6.4.4.0. You could try downloading an older release from https://github.com/adobe/aem-cif-guides-venia/releases
I think 1.9.0 should support AEM 6.4

Answer (score 0):

Without having looked too much into [aem-cif-guides-venia](https://github.com/adobe/aem-cif-guides-venia), I assume the build was successful as the dependencies are defined as run time dependencies. In other words: the build does not build the packages and bundles together with the required dependencies, but expects the dependencies to be available in the running AEM instance.

1. You need to check the bundle versions of the red marked dependencies. There might be a version mismatched or the instance had issues during startup. I suspect this to be the root cause.
2. You need to check the error log for further information.

If it is a bundle version issue, you could go an fork aem-cif-guides-venia and adjust the versions and redeploy.

I know this is not the goto answer but AEM, and OSGI specifically, is a highly dynamic application and troubleshooting is quite tricky at the beginning.